# Attach database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, attach

SQL express 2016
How to attach database (picture)??[image]

Answer (score 2):

*Dont use GUI .. instead use TSQL so you have better flexibility.*

If you have mdf (data) and ldf (log) files then (change paths as per your environment)

```
CREATE DATABASE MyAdventureWorks   
    ON (FILENAME = 'C:\MySQLServer\AdventureWorks_Data.mdf'),   
    (FILENAME = 'C:\MySQLServer\AdventureWorks_Log.ldf')   
    FOR ATTACH;
```

If you just have mdf (data) file then

```
CREATE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 
ON (FILENAME = 'C:\MySQLServer\AdventureWorks_Data.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
GO
```

if you have backup file (normally .bak) then use [restore database command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).